# android-image upload with parameters

Tags: java, android, file-upload, inputstream

I am uploading image using following code:-

```
  package com.example.image_project;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.example.imag.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    private TextView messageText;
    private Button uploadButton, btnselectpic;
    private ImageView imageview;
    private int serverResponseCode = 0;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = null;
    String userId, profileDisplayName, gender, cityId, mobile,
            isMobileVerified;
    private String upLoadServerUri = null;
    private String imagepath = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        uploadButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        messageText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.messageText);
        btnselectpic = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_selectpic);
        imageview = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView_pic);

        btnselectpic.setOnClickListener(this);
        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        upLoadServerUri = "Some URL";
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if (arg0 == btnselectpic) {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(
                    Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);
        } else if (arg0 == uploadButton) {

            dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "",
                    "Uploading file...", true);
            messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {

                    uploadFile(imagepath);

                }
            }).start();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath();

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            messageText.setText("Uploading file path:" + imagepath);

        }
    }

    public String getPath(Uri uri) {
        String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
        Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
        int column_index = cursor
                .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        return cursor.getString(column_index);
    }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {

        String fileName = sourceFileUri;

        HttpURLConnection conn = null;
        DataOutputStream dos = null;
        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary = "---------uiytuhjfndsjk";
        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
        File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

        if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

            dialog.dismiss();

            Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :" + imagepath);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    messageText.setText("Source File not exist :" + imagepath);
                }
            });

            return 0;

        } else {
            try {
                userId = "3473";
                profileDisplayName = "Anshul Khandelwal12";
                gender = "1";
                mobile = "8934567123";
                isMobileVerified = "0";
                cityId = "1";
                // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(
                        sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                // Open a HTTP connection to the URL
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                        "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                // conn.setRequestProperty("image", fileName);

                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userId\""
                        + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
                        + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + userId.length() + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(userId + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"profileDisplayName\""
                        + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
                        + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + profileDisplayName.length()
                        + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(profileDisplayName + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"gender\""
                        + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
                        + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + gender.length() + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(gender + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"mobile\""
                        + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
                        + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + mobile.length() + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(mobile + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"isMobileVerified\""
                        + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
                        + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + isMobileVerified.length()
                        + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(isMobileVerified + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"cityId\""
                        + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
                        + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Length: " + cityId.length() + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(cityId + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\";filename=\""
                        + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes("Content-Type: image/jpeg" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                // create a buffer of maximum size
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                // read file and write it into form...
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {

                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                }

                // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                // Responses from the server (code and message)
                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
                InputStream urlInputStream = conn.getInputStream();
                String json = null;
                try {
                    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(
                            new InputStreamReader(urlInputStream, "iso-8859-1"),
                            8);
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    String line = null;
                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }
                    urlInputStream.close();
                    json = sb.toString();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("Buffer Error",
                            "Error converting result " + e.toString());
                }
                JSONObject jObj;
                // try parse the string to a JSON object
                try {
                    jObj = new JSONObject(json);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
                }

                Log.d("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                        + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);
                Log.d("content",
                        "HTTP Response content is : " + json.toString() + ": "
                                + serverResponseCode);

                if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                    + " F:/wamp/wamp/www/uploads";
                            messageText.setText(msg);
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                    "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });
                }

                // close the streams //
                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                ex.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        messageText
                                .setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show();
                    }
                });

                Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                dialog.dismiss();
                e.printStackTrace();

                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {
                        messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
                Log.e("Upload file to server Exception",
                        "Exception : " + e.getMessage(), e);
            }
            dialog.dismiss();
            return serverResponseCode;

        } // End else block
    }

}
```

Here in this code i am able to upload parameters but image is not uploading.I took this code from stack over flow and some other website but it is working earlier but i don't know why it is not working.Please help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: did you seen any error if have then put logcat

Comment: try using some library like http://loopj.com/android-async-http/

Comment: @Sunil Mishra:No Error in logcat even i got response from  server that image profile is updated but profile picture is not updated

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23648537/1318946