# Upload Image to server with multiple parameters

Tags: php, android, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload Image to the Server, Which I have done and works very well. But the problem I'm facing is I want to Upload Image as well as pass some parameter with that Image like Mobile Number..

I'm very new to android and also don't know anything about `PHP` side coding,,
I have tried the following code to upload Image, I added few more lines to pass Mobile Number with that Image. I really don't know is that right way or not but please correct me if I'm wrong...

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private TextView messageText;
    private Button uploadButton, btnselectpic;
    private ImageView imageview;
    private int serverResponseCode = 0;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = null;

    private String upLoadServerUri = null;
    private String imagepath=null;
    private String usernumber="3333333333";
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        uploadButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.uploadButton);
        messageText  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.messageText);
        btnselectpic = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button_selectpic);
        imageview = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView_pic);

        btnselectpic.setOnClickListener(this);
        uploadButton.setOnClickListener(this);
        upLoadServerUri = "http://XXX.XX.X.XXX/Images/UploadToServer.php";
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        if(arg0==btnselectpic)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Complete action using"), 1);
        }
        else if (arg0==uploadButton) {

             dialog = ProgressDialog.show(MainActivity.this, "", "Uploading file...", true);
             //messageText.setText("uploading started.....");
             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                 public void run() {

                    UploadImageController.execute(,usernumber);

                      uploadFile(imagepath,usernumber);

                 }
               }).start();     
        }

    } 

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        if (requestCode == 1 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) data.getData().getPath(); 

            Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
            imagepath = getPath(selectedImageUri);
            Bitmap bitmap=BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagepath);
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
           // messageText.setText("Uploading file path:" +imagepath);

        }
    }
         public String getPath(Uri uri) {
                String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
                Cursor cursor = managedQuery(uri, projection, null, null, null);
                int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                return cursor.getString(column_index);
            }

    public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {


          String fileName = sourceFileUri;
          DataOutputStream dos = null;  
          String lineEnd = "\r\n";
          String twoHyphens = "--";
          String boundary = "*****";
          int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
          byte[] buffer;
          int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024; 

               try { 

                     // open a URL connection to the Servlet
                   FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                   URL url = new URL(upLoadServerUri);

                   // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
                   conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection(); 
                   conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
                   conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
                   conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
                   conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                   conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                   conn.setRequestProperty("uploaded_file", fileName); 
                   conn.setRequestProperty("userNumber", usernumber);


                   dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
                   dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploaded_file\";filename=\""
                                             + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

               //    dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd); 
               //    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data;
               //    number=\"userNumber\";
               //    usernumber=\""+ usernumber + "\"" + lineEnd);
               //    Log.d("number",usernumber);   
               //   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                   // create a buffer of  maximum size
                   bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available(); 

                   bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                   buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                   // read file and write it into form...
                   bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);  

                   while (bytesRead > 0) {

                     dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                     bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                     bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                     bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);   

                    }

                   // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
                   dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                   dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                   // Responses from the server (code and message)
                   serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
                   String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();

                   Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                           + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode);

                   if(serverResponseCode == 200){
                       InputStream response = conn.getInputStream();
                      String jsonReply = convertStreamToString(response);
                      Log.d("reply", jsonReply);

                       runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                      +" F:/wamp/wamp/www/uploads";
                             //   messageText.setText(msg);
                                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "File Upload Complete.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        });                
                   }    

                   //close the streams //
                   fileInputStream.close();
                   dos.flush();
                   dos.close();

              } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  ex.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                         // messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });

                  Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);  
              } catch (Exception e) {

                  dialog.dismiss();  
                  e.printStackTrace();

                  runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                      public void run() {
                         // messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      }
                  });
                  Log.e("Upload file to server Exception", "Exception : "  + e.getMessage(), e);  
              }
              dialog.dismiss();       
              return serverResponseCode; 
         }

    private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;
        try {
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                is.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return sb.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

This is the server side code to save the Image..

```
<?php

       $file_path = "uploads/";

       $file_path = $file_path . basename( $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']);
       if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'], $file_path)) {
           echo "success";
       } else{
           echo "fail";
       }
?>
```

Please tell me how I can fetch that Mobile Number at server side???

Comment: I have posted my answer, check it.

Comment: how can i post both image file and string data BasicNameValuePair from android to server in single button click.

Answer (score 3):

I have done this recently with PHP CodeIgniter:

#### Android Side:

```
/*** POST THIS CODE AFTER
dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream()); 
***/

dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=mobile_no" + lineEnd); // name=mobile_no so you have to get PHP side using mobile_no
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(mobile_number); // mobile_no is String variable
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
```

#### PHP Side (Core PHP):

```
$mobile_no = $_POST['mobile_no'];
```

#### PHP Side (Using CodeIgniter Framework):

```
$mobile_no => $this->input->post('mobile_no');
```

Comment: Does this still work? i am having similar issues, can you please check my question out! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36242600/upload-multipart-string-to-server-w-post-php/36243550?noredirect=1#comment60119192_36243550

Comment: thanks for the quick response but i am trying to get it to work on my app right now and i am not having any luck! :/

Comment: found a lot to send parameters and here I got the great answer. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$mobileNumber = $_POST['userNumber']; // get mobile number from post
```

Since you are using `POST` method:

```
conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
```

And setting mobile number as:

```
conn.setRequestProperty("userNumber", usernumber);
```