# upload video and variable to server?

Tags: java, android, video

**UPDATE** answer is here :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/23648537/6042879

i want to be able to upload my video and a variable to my server to use in the PHP script.

So far i can choose the video i want from my phone and upload it perfectly fine to the server but cant figure out exactly how to send the variable with the video. I can do them separately but it wont work if i combine them.

i use this code to use to upload variables:

```
//Uploads the product details
        try {//Try block is to see if the call to the database can work.
            URL url = new URL(ProductDetails_URL);//Create a new URL and put there variable "register_URL" into it.
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();//Create a httpConnection and open it
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");//Use the request method
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

            OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));

            String data = URLEncoder.encode("ProductOwnerEmail", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(ProductOwnerEmail, "UTF-8") + "&" +
          URLEncoder.encode(DescriptionPoint3, "UTF-8");

            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            OS.close();

            InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            IS.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) { //url.openConnection() catch statement
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Video upload code:

```
try{
                FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
                URL url = new URL(UploadVideo_URL);
                conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                conn.setDoInput(true);
                conn.setDoOutput(true);
                conn.setUseCaches(false);
                conn.setRequestMethod("POST");

                conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
                conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
                conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
                conn.setRequestProperty("myFile", selectedPath);
                dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"myFile\";filename=\"" + selectedPath + "\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);






                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data;      name=\"Details\";Email=\"" + ProductOwnerEmail + "\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.write(ProductOwnerEmail.getBytes());
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"Details\";KeyCode=\"" + ProductKeyCode + "\"" + lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.write(ProductOwnerEmail.getBytes());
                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);








                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                Log.i("Huzza", "Initial .available : " + bytesAvailable);

                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

                while (bytesRead > 0) {
                    dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                    bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                    bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                    bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                }

                dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
                dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

                serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();

                fileInputStream.close();
                dos.flush();
                dos.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Product upload failed";
            }
```

PHP code:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
$file_name = $_FILES['myFile']['name'];
$file_size = $_FILES['myFile']['size'];
$file_type = $_FILES['myFile']['type'];
$temp_name = $_FILES['myFile']['tmp_name'];






$ProductOwnerEmail = $_FILES['Details']['Email'];
$ProductKeyCode = $_FILES['Details']['KeyCode'];

$NewDirectory = "/var/www/html/ProductVideos/" . $ProductOwnerEmail;

if (!file_exists($NewDirectory))
{
    mkdir($NewDirectory, 0777, true);
}






$location = "/var/www/html/ProductVideos/$ProductOwnerEmail/" .    $ProductKeyCode;//$NewDirectory . '/' . $file_name;

move_uploaded_file($temp_name, $location);
echo   "Uploaded!";
}else{
echo "Error";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

After you code:

```
dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"myFile\";filename=\"" + SelectedPDF + "\"" + lineEnd);
dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
```

Write something like below to send variables:

```
dos.writeBytes(LINE_END);

// Loop a list of variable that you want to send to server.
/*for (StringKeyValuePair pair : yourVariableList) {
    dos.writeBytes(TWO_HYPHENS + BOUNDARY + LINE_END);
    dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"" + pair.getKey()+  "\"" + LINE_END);
    dos.writeBytes(LINE_END);
    dos.write(pair.getValue().getBytes());
    dos.writeBytes(LINE_END);
}*/

dos.writeBytes(TWO_HYPHENS + BOUNDARY + LINE_END);
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"ProductOwnerEmail\"" + LINE_END);
dos.writeBytes(LINE_END);
dos.write(ProductOwnerEmail.getBytes());
dos.writeBytes(LINE_END);

dos.writeBytes(TWO_HYPHENS + BOUNDARY + LINE_END);
dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"ProductKeyCode\"" + LINE_END);
dos.writeBytes(LINE_END);
dos.write(ProductKeyCode.getBytes());
dos.writeBytes(LINE_END);
```

Comment: As what I mention, StringKeyValuePair is class create by myself. You have to implements yours. Basically, just replace the .getKey() with your variable name and .getValue() with value that you want to send over.

Comment: in the PHP do i use $name = $_POST['name'];? and ill try this!

Comment: also what do i put for _yourVariableList_?

Comment: are those two methods your own? because if they are can you update your answer with examples please!! :)

Comment: Basically it is list of variables that you want to pass over to server when you uploading your video. In your case, i believe is `ProductOwnerEmail` and `ProductKeyCode`. However, I remarked it and hardcode it for your better understanding.

Comment: thanks for the update! ill take a look at it now but how should the PHP look!

Comment: Sorry @user6042879, I am not familiar with PHP. Normally when you perform a HTTP post to PHP, how you get a variable? I believe you need to use sometime like `$ProductOwnerEmail = $_POST["ProductOwnerEmail"];` instead and not from `$_FILES`.

Comment: okay so far you've helped me alot so ill see what i can done here and if this helped me then ill mark it was correct! If i have any other quetions ill ask you

Comment: I figured out how to do it! its similar to this code but the correct answer is this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23648537/6042879

Comment: ok. It look same as my answer which need to $_POST instead. Anyways, it is great that you get the answer.

Answer (score 0):

U can use Volley lib  for this purpose. It also Keep your requests in a queue and easy to use http://developer.android.com/training/volley/index.html